# Using the find() function with sets

Tags: c++, iterator, find, set

I have just encountered this chapter in my book and I dont really understand how find() works. I tried to create a simple function to check how the find() function works, but I am getting a multitude of errors in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

set<int> setA(1,2);


int item;
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> item;

int setIter;
setIter = setA.find(item);
if (setIter != setA.end())
{
  cout << "It's in the list." << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't initialize a set with setA(1,2)  The constructor that takes two parameters takes a comparator and an allocator.  Try `set<int> setA = {1,2};`  - that may not work either if you aren't using a new C++ compiler and if it doesn't you will need to call insert()

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct implementation of your program...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    set<int> setA;
    setA.insert(1);                 // use insert function
    setA.insert(2);
    set<int>::iterator setIter;    // take set iterator

    int item;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> item;

    setIter = setA.find(item);
    if (setIter != setA.end())
    {
      cout << "It's in the list." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You are making two mistakes in your program. First you are initializing set using constructor which does not work so you have to use insert function of set. Secondly you are taking iterator as an int which is not correct. Iterator is basically a pointer of set type. So you have to take the iterator of set

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two issues- first is the usage of constructor and the other is assigning set iterator returned by set.find() to an int. Here is the corrected code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <set> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    set<int> setA({1,2});

    int item;
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> item;

    set<int>::iterator setIter = setA.find(item);

    if (setIter != setA.end())
    {
      cout << "It's in the list." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```